# React - iterating over key value pairs in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I cant get this snippet to output `tacos`

im not sure what I am doing wrong

```
    let tacos = [{ John: "Guacamole" }, { Sally: "Beef" }, { Greg: "Bean" }];

class Parent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parent-component">
        <h3>List of tacos:</h3>
        <TacosList tacos={tacos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TacosList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tacos-list">
        {this.props.tacos.map((taco) => {
          return 

          <Parent taco={taco}/>

        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: It looks like you've defined a `TacosList` in terms of `Parent`, and you've defined `Parent` in terms of a `TacosList`, and it's going to create an infinite loop.

Comment: maybe this example useful for you https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/NRZYGN?editors=0010

Comment: Mmmm, I'm hungry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are breaking into a new line in after **`return`** which it's returning **`undefined`** while iterating the `tacos` list.

Furthermore, You will create an infinite loop rendering if you call **`<Parent />`** inside **`<TacosList />`**

Either you create a new component to render the items or you do it within the **`<TacosList />`** component

```js
let tacos = [{
  person: "John",
  ingredient: 'Guacamole'
 }, {
  person: 'Sally',
  ingredient: 'Beef'
 }, {
  person: 'Greg',
  ingredient: 'Bean'
 }];

class Parent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parent-component">
        <h3>List of tacos:</h3>
        <TacosList tacos={tacos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TacosList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tacos-list">
        {this.props.tacos.map((taco, index) => (
         <p key={index}>{taco.person}: {taco.ingredient}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
<Parent taco={taco}/>
```

First parent is not expecting a taco property.

Second I think you intend to actually render the elements to display the taco information there, not a Parent component for each taco.

Answer (score 0):

Start up with creating an atomic component (div, span or IMG) to show the tacos list, in `TacosList`.

The map in `TacosList` will work only at the first level, because every item is a JavaScript object, which means you have to know the key, to have the value, or use `Object.keys` and `Object.items` to show names.